# Is a transit visa required for a layover in Bangkok

Tags: transit-visas

I am travelling from Cebu to Mumbai with layover of 6 hours in Bangkok with different airlines, do I need a transit visa?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: single ticket or multiple tickets? Checked baggage ?